# javascript call inside php where loop not working and breaks query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, loops

I am attempting to call a javascript function inside a php where loop.   I've succeeded in calling the variable, however the function only works on the first line, and then breaks a subsequent query.

The javascript is a simple show/hide of a div or span tag with a specific id.  I'm trying to have this appear for every instance of a variable, but only open the span associated with that entry, so I used a php variable from the query.

The javascript code is contained in the header; it works fine without the php, and the php works fine without the javascript but I can't seem to make them work together.

Here's the code:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qir)) {
        $ingredient_id = $row['ingredient_id'];
        echo  '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $ingredient_id . '" name="markdelete[]">';


            echo $row['amt'] . ' ' .$row['ingredient_name']; ?> <button onclick="showHide('<?php echo $row['ingredient_id']; ?>'); return false">Edit amount</button> <br />
             <span id="<?php echo $row['ingredient_id']; ?>" class="hide">

            <?php include_once('amt.php'); 
            echo '</span> ';  
        //  }
        echo '<br />';


    }
    echo '<input type ="submit" name="remove" value="Remove">';
```

First of all, the `showHide` is only working on the first record

It is also making this query not respond at all.

```
if (isset($_POST['remove']))  {

    iF (!empty($_POST['markdelete'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['markdelete'] as $delete_id)   {


        //   remove specific source from source_subject


           $rem_ing = "DELETE from dish_ingredient 
                       where ingredient_id = $delete_id
                       and dish_id = $dish_id ";
           mysqli_query($dbc, $rem_ing)
             or die ('Error removing ingredient: '.mysqli_error($dbc));   



        }
    }
}
```

I tried removing the `return false;`, to no avail.  Please let me know if I need to show more of the code (e.g. the javascript itself)

Edit:

I've tried working within the php string (this is actually what I had tried first) but it seems to break everything (no javascript, no php)

```
            echo $row['amt'] . ' ' .$row['ingredient_name'] . '<button onclick="showHide(\''. $row['ingredient_id'] .'\') return false">Edit amount</button> <br />';
             echo '<span id=" '. $row['ingredient_id'] .' " class="hide">';

            include_once('amt.php'); 
            echo '</span> ';
```

Edit:  I am open to other solutions if this is not something that is possible.  I'm feeling a bit stumped.   Realistically I just want to have a list of items called from a mysql database, and have a field appear onclick to edit an associated variable if desired without having to send it to another page or reload the script for usability (hence the javascript piece).

Thanks again, anyone who can assist.

Note:  this is the script that I am calling:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    menu_status = new Array();

    function showHide(theid){
        if (document.getElementById) {
        var switch_id = document.getElementById(theid);

            if(menu_status[theid] != 'show') {
               switch_id.className = 'show';
               menu_status[theid] = 'show';
            }else{
               switch_id.className = 'hide';
               menu_status[theid] = 'hide';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: in PHP you can't expect `<?php echo` to work since you're already echoing. it should be this: `showHide(\''.$row['ingredient_id'].'\');` for example. Looks like you have a misunderstanding of the use of strings in PHP

Comment: To expand on that, you use `<?php echo ... ?>` when you use `?>` to exit from script mode into HTML mode, not when you use `echo`.

Comment: If you look closer, you'll see I had exited php first in order to execute the javascript.  The problem seems to be that the javascript calls don't seem to work within the php block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after a long time on this, I finally figured out what was going on.  Part of the issue was that I was trying to call a form inside a form, which I had forgotten is not permitted in HTML, so this required some redesign.

Other issues involved calling loops within inside loops, which caused problems where the first record would work, but not for the remaining records.

The javascript above did not need to be modified, only the way that it was called.

Here is what worked.  The main key was using `include()` instead of `include_once()`.

```
while($r = $qir->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ingredient_id = $r['ingredient_id'];
    $amt = $r['amt'];
    $ingredient_name = $r['ingredient_name'];

        echo $r['amt'] . ' ' .$r['ingredient_name'];
        if ($row['user_id'] == $user_id) {
            echo ' <span class="openlink"><button onclick="showHide(\''.$ingredient_id. '\')">edit amount</button></span><br/>';

            echo '<div id="'.$ingredient_id.'" class="hide">';

            include('amt1.php');

            echo '</div>';
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need  tag there as you are already in php block.Try it without  and use

```
showHide(\''.$row['ingredient_id'].'\')
```

and change

```
   <?php include_once(....);
```

to

```
   include_once(........);
```

Hopefully that would work

Comment: Okay, following your advice, I removed the dropping out of php and included the javascript and html inline, and attempted to fix it with this:

`    echo $row['amt'] . ' ' .$row['ingredient_name'] . '<button onclick="showHide(\''. $row['ingredient_id'] .'\') return false">Edit amount</button> <br />';
     echo '<span id=" '. $row['ingredient_id'] .' " class="hide">';`

but now the javascript is not working at all and the delete function still does not work either.   Am I misnuderstanding?

Comment: can you try <input type=submit> instead of button.And don't use return false.Let me know what happens

Comment: does your echo show you the values and the button after the edit??

Comment: no effect.  I used the button because it's better than using an href for an blank anchor.  Submit made no difference.  (the jst is called on  onClick;  my understanding is it doesn't matter _what_ is clicked, as long as it is for that tag to work)

the reason for the return false was specifically to prevent the page from reloading;  it kept calling the entire php file, which should not happen with a simple show/hide.  I tried removing it and it also made no difference.

the reason I had escaped the php in the first place was because it was the only way to get the javascript to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

===========
try this for you javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

    function showHide(theid){

        if (document.getElementById) {

          var switch_id = document.getElementById(theid);

          if(!switch_id) {

            switch_id.className = (switch_id.className.indexOf("show") > -1) ? "hide" : "show"

          }

        }
}
```